# Insert parameter values and JSON string values

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I tried to create a stored procedure to insert data by `JSON` and `Parameter`

```
Declare @PaymentJson        Nvarchar(1000)  = N'{"type":4},{"type":1`},{"type":2},{"type":3}'  
        ,@ProductID         bigint  = 5
        ,@UserCode          bigint  = 2

Insert into PaymentType ([ProductID], [PaymentType],[UserCode])
            SELECT @ProductID,
                    PaymentType = MAX(CASE WHEN LOWER([key]) = 'type' THEN [value] END),
                    @UserCode
            FROM OPENJSON(@PaymentJson)
```

Result is not true, is 1 first JSON (in this case type is 4) row.

> (1 row affected)

I need, the required number of `JSON` strings , insert into row `PaymentType` in this case should be:

> (4 row affected)

```
ProductID   PaymentType UserCode
5           4           2
5           1           2
5           2           2
5           3           2
```

My DBMS is SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this unexpected behaviour is the fact, that the input JSON is not valid (multiple root elements), but `OPENJSON()` parses successfully the first object from this invalid JSON (although `ISJSON()` returns `0`). As a workaround you need to transform the input JSON into a valid JSON array and parse it with `OPENJSON()` and explicit schema with the appropriate column definition:

```
DECLARE 
   @PaymentJson nvarchar(1000) = N'{"type":4},{"type":1},{"type":2},{"type":3}',
   @ProductID bigint = 5,
   @UserCode bigint = 2

INSERT INTO PaymentType ([ProductID], [PaymentType], [UserCode])
SELECT 
   @ProductID,
   [Type],
   @UserCode
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('[', @PaymentJson, ']')) WITH ([Type] int '$.type')
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer , its worked correctly .

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your JSON string is not valid it must be an array

```
N'[{"type":4},{"type":1},{"type":2},{"type":3}]'
```

second, you don't need to use an aggregate function in the select statement

so your code should be like this:

```
Declare @PaymentJson        Nvarchar(1000)  = N'[{"type":4},{"type":1},{"type":2},{"type":3}]'  
        ,@ProductID         bigint  = 5
        ,@UserCode          bigint  = 2

Insert into PaymentType ([ProductID], [PaymentType],[UserCode])
            SELECT @ProductID,
                    PaymentType = (CASE WHEN LOWER([key]) = 'type' THEN [value] END),
                    @UserCode
            FROM OPENJSON(@PaymentJson)
```

Comment: Hi, i try it , i have a error : Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PaymentType', table 'PaymentType'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. then commented insert and use select, its tru, return null